# My iPad Mini won't turn on after charging

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

Last night I went to use my iPad and found the battery was completely drained. So, I charged it, after a few minutes it turned back on, and I looked at the battery symbol and it had said that it was at 62% battery life.

I was somewhat confused, as just moments before it was completely dead. I left it to charge for a bit before taking it off charge to charge my iPod.

The next morning the iPad was dead again. I put it on charger and all that happened was the logo would pop up, fade away, and repeat. I left it alone to charge and when I tried to turn it on, nothing happened. I've only had the iPad for two months, and this is the first time anything like this has happened.

It hasn't been dropped or damaged at all, at least to my knowledge. Any advice? I really don't feel like spending money at the Apple Store for them to tell me it's just some fault in my charger or something. I've tried most everything, including the Home/Sleep-Wake button reset.

Comment: I would have thought the iPad and it's charger would still be under warranty. . Also seeing a genus should be free. So it should not cost you anything. Go see them if anything they will just swap it out for a new one straight away.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not near an Apple store or Authorised Service Provider then call up AppleCare (apple.com/contact) and they will help you try a few steps and if they come to the conclusion that your iPad needs to be swapped then they will send you one. Pretty sweet deal. I encourage purchasing AppleCare+ as well while you talk to the phone agent because you have a small period of time to purchase it and it is a fantastic investment.